# Sorting - speed and performance

Tags: java, performance, sorting

I am sorting players on my game on a list by rank order so, first an admin, then moderator, all the way till it goes to a player. Here is my code for that part:

```
/*
     * 2 -> Administrator, 1 -> Moderator, 6 -> Supporter, 14 -> Dicer, 8 -> Ultra
     * Donator, 13 -> Extreeme Donator, 9 -> Donator
     */

    Integer[] sortedRanksRights = { 2, 1, 6, 14, 8, 13, 9, 0 };
    ArrayList<Player> sortedPlayers = new ArrayList<Player>();

    // Loop over and add the sorted players to the list according to ranks
    for (int i = 0; i < sortedRanksRights.length; i++) {
        for (Player pp : World.getPlayers()) {
            if (pp.getRights() != sortedRanksRights[i])
                continue;
            else
                sortedPlayers.add(pp);
        }
    }
```

It works well!!
But then I had an idea of sorting admins between themselves as 
Owner, co-owner, then other admins. And here is my code for the second part:

```
    if (sortedPlayers.size() > 1) {
        int place = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < Settings.MAIN_ACESSS.length; i++) {
            if (World.getPlayerByDisplayName(Settings.MAIN_ACESSS[i]) != null) {
                if (!sortedPlayers.get(place).getUsername().toLowerCase()
                        .equals(Settings.MAIN_ACESSS[i].toLowerCase())) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < sortedPlayers.size(); j++) {
                        if (!sortedPlayers.get(place).getUsername().toLowerCase()
                                .equals(Settings.MAIN_ACESSS[i].toLowerCase())) {
                            Player target = sortedPlayers.get(place);
                            Player mine = sortedPlayers.get(j);
                            sortedPlayers.set(place, mine);
                            sortedPlayers.set(j, target);
                            place++;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    place++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

main_access has the owner and co-owner names.

This works too, but I don't think that it is the best way to achieve such thing. Looking to the code that I even wrote makes me confused ahaha. So let me explain it.

This checks if there is more than 1 player playing the game to sort, then runs a loop to main_access which have the owner, then the co-owner names on the array and checks if they are online. If so, it checks if the first name on the sorted List is not the owner. It then runs a loop to check where the owner in the list is and replaces both players so that the owner is on top of the list. I hope this was not confusing.

Is my approach good? If not, is there any advise? The game could have thousand players playing, so speed and performance is considered.

Comment: Why not use `Collections` to store the players and use `Comparator` interface to define the ordering in a more easier way ?

Comment: Wouldn't `Collections.sort()` or `Arrays.sort()` with a proper `Comparator` work for you? That way you could separate the sorting algorithm from the comparison logic (i.e. how the order is determined).

Comment: Side note: instead of `xxx.toLowerCase().equals(yyy.toLowerCase())` you could use `xxx.equalsIgnoreCase(yyy)` - shorter and more readable

Comment: Actually I don't know about collections yet. I am far new to programming and didn't run into collections. I will go do a research about them, thanks for the information. Also, I would appreciate and be glad if you could give me a sample code regarding this on my current question. Thanks!!

Comment: Is it normal that you made this comparison twice, with the 'i' variable :
`if (!sortedPlayers.get(place).getUsername().toLowerCase().equals(Settings.MAIN_ACESSS[i].toLowerCase())) {`

Comment: Btw, do the ranks have to have such seemingly arbitrary numbers? It would be easier if you could assign the rank a number according to their priority. If not, then you could use either a map of right to priority (e.g. `2->0, 1->1, 6->2, ...`) and do a lookup for 2 players or (better) use an enum for the rank and give each enum instance a priority which you can compare (you've probably not arrived at enums yet but they're not too complex and should help _a lot_) .

Answer (score 2):

If the brackets of the sorting category are static and never going to change. You can use [bucket sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_sort) that will give you O(n).

Idea is to arrange the objects in various buckets (in your case 2 levels of buckets), and traverse the buckets in fixed way.

For example:

For input:

```
player1: Moderator
player2: admin
player3: Donator
player4: Dicer
```

You need to traverse and organize it into something like this,

```
Admin: [player2]
Moderator: [player1]
Donator: [player3]
Dicer: [player4]
```

Now you just need to iterate through these buckets in fixed order and read out the players inside it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a suggestion of how you could sort players based on rank and other properties based on collections etc. I'll somewhat divert from your code but I hope you still get it.

First, let's define the enum `Rank`

```
enum Rank { 
  Administrator(1), 
  Moderator(2), 
  ...;

  //note that you could use the ordinal, i.e. position of the value as the priority 
  //but doing it that way allows you to use some other ordering if needed
  private final priority;

  Rank(int prio ) {
    priority = prio;
  }

  public int getPriority() {
    return prio;
  }
}
```

And another enum for their status (here we use the ordinal for demonstration purposes):

```
enum Status {
  OWNER,
  CO_OWNER,
  PLAYER
}
```

Now we have a list of players for a game (I'm using a list because we need a sortable collection):

```
List<Player> players = ...;
```

Then we sort it:

```
Collections.sort(players, new Comparator<Player>() {
  public int compare( Player left, Player right) {
    //first compare by rank priority
    int r = left.getRank().getPriority().compareTo(right.getRank().getPriority());

    //If ranks are equal, compare by status. 
    //If that should only happen for a certain rank, e.g. ADMINISTRATOR, 
    //then additionally check && left.getRank() == ADMINISTOR.
    //Assuming ranks have different priorities, if r is 0 that means both have the same rank
    if( r == 0 ) {
      r = left.getStatus().compareTo(right.getStatus());
    }

    //finally sort players by their name if rank and status are equal
    if( r == 0 ) {
      r = left.getUsername().compareToIgnoreCase(right.getUsername());
    }

    return r;
  }
});
```

With Java 8 the comparator could also be constructed like this (I can't compile right now so there might be errors):

```
Comparator<Player> comp = Comparator.comparing( player -> player.getRank().getPriority() )
                                    .thenComparing( player -> player.getStatus() )
                                    .thenComparing( player -> player.getUsername().toLowercase() );
```

Comment: Thanks but I have this undefined.. left.getRank() and left.getStatus() ??

Comment: @qistarlei.ba that why I said I'll divert somewhat from your code. You could either define that in `Player` or adapt your code to what's actually there. The problem is that we have no information on what `Player` looks like.

Answer (score 0):

I advise not trying to roll your own sorting method, instead just make `Player` Comparable and call `sort` on your list of players. Also, maybe make your ranks Classes or enum members.

```
public static class Player implements Comparable<Player> {
    public enum Rank {
        OWNER, CO_OWNER, ADMINISTRATOR, MODERATOR, SUPPORTER, DICER, ULTRA_DONOR, EXTREME_DONOR, DONATOR, NEWBIE
    }

    Rank rank; // init the players rank.

    @Override public int compareTo(Player o) {
        return rank.ordinal() - o.rank.ordinal();
    }

    // List<Player> players = ...;
    // Collections.sort(players);
}
```

If you don't want to use Classes or an enum and still want to stick with ints, then I recommend making the ints represent the ranks in the order that you want them sorted `(0 -> Owner, 1 -> Co Owner, 2 -> Administrator)`  so that you can still do `compareTo(Player o){ return rank - o.rank; }`.

Comment: As I understand it, OWNER and CO_OWNER would not be ranks but roles, i.e. a player can be admin _and_ owner etc.

Comment: In this scheme owners can still be treated as admins but are above plain ol' admins. In the case of a game server, I would assume owners could un-admin someone below them thus they should still probably be separate ranks.